# Add prefix to all routes, links and urls

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

Is it possible to add some prefix to all routes, urls and links in the whole application at one place including blades?
For example I have route

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

but instead of it I want to have

```
Route::get($prefix . '/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

and in blade

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

to

```
{{ HTML::style($prefix . 'css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

I tried

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => $prefix), function() {});
```

but it did not apply prefix to links in blades.

Comment: Are you sure that's the thing you really want? Laravel is meant to run in webroot, the public folder being the one accessible from outside world. I'd consider using subdomains instead, if you want to run multiple applications on the same domain or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I have no another choice, because I must use specific server. All files are saved in `/var/www/test/test`, but I do not have access to first test and my app runs on _example.org/test_. When I want to go for example to _example.org/test/login_, I must use `Route::get('test/login', '...');` instead of `Route::get('/login', '...');`. So it is quite annoying to write routes and links in this way when migrating application from localhost to this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found simple solution. I created `.env.php` folder inside project which looks like

```
return array(
    'ROUTES_PREFIX' => 'prefix',
);
```

then added this code to all routes

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => $_ENV['ROUTES_PREFIX']), function() { 
    // routes here
});
```

and created custom macro for `style`, `script` and `image`. For example my macro for `style` looks like this

```
HTML::macro('extendedStyle', function($url, $attributes = array(), $secure = null) {
    $prefix = $_ENV['ROUTES_PREFIX'] == '' ? '' : $_ENV['ROUTES_PREFIX'] . '/';
    return HTML::style($prefix . $url, $attributes, $secure);
});
```

I hope, someone will find this useful.